# WP Enfold Layerslider: How to put static content above the slider?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I need just a little bit of further help. I wanna put static content overlaying WP Layerslider. Just like the search form on this website:

http://bit.ly/1l8XIbH

But everytime I put content above it, it still gets into the background. The reason is the JS of Layerslider.

I use Enfold WP Theme and WP Layerslider

Any suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution on the help desk of WP Theme creator:

http://www.kriesi.at/support/topic/wp-enfold-layerslider-how-to-put-static-content-above-the-slider/

```
#after_layer_slider_1 .flex_column.av_one_third.avia-builder-el-3 {
position: relative;
top: -200px;
background: red; /* remove this, it's for visual purposes */
height: 1000px; /* remove this, it's for visual purposes */
}

#after_layer_slider_1 {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Works perfectly fine! :)

Hope I could help people with similar problems

Cheers